# Visual Studio Addin - "file in zombie state" error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I'm building a visual studio add-in. I copy a solution and do various things to the files inside its and the folder structure. I then load it into visual studio and proceed to load a list of predefined files however when I do this I get an exception and a message saying the files cannot be access for they are in a zombie state.

Here is my code for opening and loading in my Connect.cs

```
    public void OpenCodeFile(String file)
    {
        try
        {
            _applicationObject.Documents.Open(file, Constants.vsViewKindCode, false);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void OpenSolution(String file)
    {
        _applicationObject.Solution.Open(file);
    }

    private DTE2 _applicationObject;
    private AddIn _addInInstance;
```

Comment: Point a shotgun at the monitor and pull the trigger. Problem solved. :P

Comment: Or feed it a part of your brain... If you can spare it

Comment: I get that error with aspnet_wp.exe all the time.  I would love to know how to stop it, without the previous 2 suggestions.

Comment: "Cannot access data for the desired file since it is in a zombie state."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my problem with the following code:

```
    public void OpenCodeFile(String file)
    {
        try
        {
            _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", file);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```